# Rxjava unsubscribe does not stop emitting events

Tags: java, rx-java

I have a hot observable that emits items, to which I subscribe a basic action method (or whatever subscriber).

My problem is that when I call unsubscribe on the subscription, I still reveive event.

See my test below :

```
ManualOnSubscribe<Long> emitter = new ManualOnSubscribe<>();

Subscription sub = Observable.create(emitter).subscribe(aLong -> LOGGER.info("receive {}", aLong));

LOGGER.info("emit 1");
emitter.emit(Long.valueOf(1));

LOGGER.info("is unsubscribed ? {}", sub.isUnsubscribed());
sub.unsubscribe();
LOGGER.info("is unsubscribed ? {}", sub.isUnsubscribed());

LOGGER.info("emit 2");
emitter.emit(Long.valueOf(2));
```

code of ManualOnSubscribe :

```
private Set<Subscriber<? super T>> subscribers;

public ManualOnSubscribe() {
    subscribers = new HashSet<Subscriber<? super T>>();
}

@Override
public void call(Subscriber<? super T> subscriber) {
    subscribers.add(subscriber);
}

public void emit(T item) {
    subscribers.stream().forEach(subscriber -> subscriber.onNext(item));
}
```

And when I run the test I have :

```
(TestUnsubscribe.java:22) - emit 1
(TestUnsubscribe.java:20) - receive 1
(TestUnsubscribe.java:25) - is unsubscribed ? false
(TestUnsubscribe.java:27) - is unsubscribed ? true
(TestUnsubscribe.java:27) - emit 2
(TestUnsubscribe.java:20) - receive 2
```

When I read the javadoc I feel I'm doing the right thing, but it's not working, does someone has already run into the same problem ?
Thank you for reading.

Comment: If you are using `Observable.create()` you have to manage unsubscription on your own. Why don't you use PublishSubject or one of the RxRelay types instead?

Comment: It works like a charm. I didn't knew about PublishSubject. I still feel that any Observable (even obtained by Observable.create) should implement the unsubscribe contract. You should make your comment an answer so I can set it as resolved.